# Barbell in a Room

Tags: trigonometry

A 7' x 7' room contains a 7' barbell placed in the center of the room, parallel to the north and south walls.  How many degrees must the barbell be turned in order to provide exactly 1' of separation between each end of the barbell and the nearest wall?

Comment: Did you study some trig?

Comment: Clearly not more than 45 degrees or you will be closer to the east-west wall than the north-south walls.  But nearly every bit of 45 degrees will be required.  Tell us a function that might give the distance of the tip of the barbell from some wall.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$\cos^{-1} \frac {2.5}{3.5} = \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]{\cos^{-1} \frac {5}{7} }$

Comment: +1 I like the diagram. What did you use to draw it?

Comment: @almagest Powerpoint 2010, has a nice "Save as Picture" option (on a selected set of drawing objects).